# How do I subclass or otherwise extend a pandas DataFrame without breaking DataFrame.append()?

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

I have a complex object I'd like to build around a pandas DataFrame. I've tried to do this with a subclass, but appending to the DataFrame reinitializes all properties in a new instance even when using `_metadata`, as recommended [here](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/development/extending.html#subclassing-pandas-data-structures). I know subclassing pandas objects is not recommended but I don't know how to do what I want with composition (or any other method), so if someone can tell me how to do this without subclassing that would be great.

I'm working with the following code:

```
import pandas as pd

class thisDF(pd.DataFrame):

    @property
    def _constructor(self):
        return thisDF

    _metadata = ['new_property']

    def __init__(self, data=None, index=None, columns=None, copy=False, new_property='reset'):
        
        super(thisDF, self).__init__(data=data, index=index, columns=columns, dtype='str', copy=copy)

        self.new_property = new_property

cols = ['A', 'B', 'C']
new_property = cols[:2]
tdf = thisDF(columns=cols, new_property=new_property)
```

As in the examples I linked to above, operations like `tdf[['A', 'B']].new_property` work fine. However, modifying the data in a way that creates a new copy initializes a new instance that doesn't retain `new_property`. So the code

```
print(tdf.new_property)
tdf = tdf.append(pd.Series(['a', 'b', 'c'], index=tdf.columns), ignore_index=True)
print(tdf.new_property)
```

outputs

```
['A', 'B']
reset
```

How do I extend `pd.DataFrame` so that `thisDF.append()` retains instance attributes (or some equivalent data structure if not using a subclass)? Note that I can do everything I want by making a class with a DataFrame as an attribute, but I don't want to do `my_object.dataframe.some_method()` for all DataFrame operations.

Comment: What do you want your complex object to do that is leading to you subclassing DataFrame? Often times I create a class that has dataframe as an attribute and functions within that class may manipulate the dataframe. For instance `my_object.add_stuff(x)` might call `self.dataframe.append(x)`.

Comment: The object represents a citation network with a DataFrame for the bibliography, a DataFrame of sources and targets for the citations, and a NetworkX graph for network analysis. The citations and graph are attributes, but I would like to manipulate the bibliography by doing `my_object.DataFrameMethod()` rather than doing `my_object.bib.DataFrameMethod()` or wrapping all DataFrame methods with `my_object` class methods (because I'm assuming that would be a lot of work, correct?).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"[...] or wrapping all DataFrame methods with my_object class methods (because I'm assuming that would be a lot of work, correct?)"

No it doesn't have to be a lot of work. You actually don't have to wrap every function of the wrapped object yourself. You can use getattr to pass calls down to your wrapped object like this:

```
class WrappedDataFrame:
    def __init__(self, df, new_property):
        self._df = df
        self.new_property = new_property
    
    def __getattr__(self, attr):
        if attr in self.__dict__:
            return getattr(self, attr)
        return getattr(self._df, attr)
    
    def __getitem__(self, item):
        return self._df[item]
    
    def __setitem__(self, item, data):
        self._df[item] = data
```

`__getattr__` is a dunder method that is called every time you call a method of an instance of that class. In my implementation, every time `__getattr__` is implicitly called, it checks if the object has the method you are calling. If it does, that method is returned and executed. Otherwise, it will look for that method in the `__dict__`of the wrapped object and return that method.

So this class works almost exactly like a DataFrame for the most part. You could now just implement the methods you want to behave differently like append in your example.

You could either make it so that append modifies the wrapped DataFrame object

```
    def append(self, *args, **kwargs):
        self._df = self._df.append(*args, **kwargs)
```

or so that it returns a new instance of the `WrappedDataFrame` class, which of course keeps all your functionality.

```
    def append(self, *args, **kwargs):
        return self.__class__(self._df.append(*args, **kwargs))
```

Comment: This looks like it's going to work for me, thanks! I'd tried to do this but I didn't handle get/set item correctly.

Comment: For others who don't know what they're doing, `try: return getattr(self, attr)` `except: foo` in `__getattr__` will kill the kernel. Use `try: return self.__getattribute__(attr)` `except: foo` instead.