Add a list property to a pd.DataFrame subclass
I'm using a subclass of pandas' DataFrame class. The subclass needs to have a property that is a list. Here's an example:
import pandas as pd

class MyDataFrame(pd.DataFrame):
    def __init__(self, data, colors, *args, **kwargs):
        m = pd.DataFrame(data)
        super().__init__(m, *args, **kwargs)
        self.colors = colors

my_df = MyDataFrame(
    {
        "name": ["Fred", "Wilma"],
        "age": [42, 38]
    },
    colors=["red", "yellow", "green"])

This gets me the following warning on self.colors = colors:

UserWarning: Pandas doesn't allow columns to be created via a new attribute name - see https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#attribute-access

It appears that the problem is DataFrame's feature of treating column headers as attributes and interpreting the "self.colors = colors" line as a request to add a column to the DataFrame, which it very reasonable declines to do. I've tried added a setter without effect. I also tried moving the attribute assignment above the super().__init__ call, but ended up in an infinite recursion. What can I do to fix this?

Beside the point, but m seems unnecessary here. Just do super().__init__(data, *args, **kwargs).

Link moved here: https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#attribute-access

Is this what you're looking for? How to disable Python warnings? e.g. with warnings.catch_warnings(action="ignore", category=UserWarning): self.colors = colors

Why do you want to subclass the df class in the first place? You can have a custom object that carries the df data itself and any other attribute you want

Did you check https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65375177/how-do-i-subclass-or-otherwise-extend-a-pandas-dataframe-without-breaking-datafr ?

You can add arbitrary data (effectively metadata) to a DataFrame using its attrs property, but the documentation does come with this caveat:

attrs is experimental and may change without warning.

That said attrs has been "experimental" for a few years now, and this should work:
import pandas as pd

class MyDataFrame(pd.DataFrame):
    def __init__(self, data, colors, *args, **kwargs):
        # as was mentioned, you don't really need the intermediate DataFrame 'm'
        super().__init__(data, *args, **kwargs)
        super().attrs['colors'] = colors


my_df = MyDataFrame(
    {
        "name": ["Fred", "Wilma"],
        "age": [42, 38]
    },
    colors=["red", "yellow", "green"])


print(my_df)
print(my_df.attrs['colors'])

    name  age
0   Fred   42
1  Wilma   38
['red', 'yellow', 'green']

However, I think I agree with @roganjosh - you may be better served by not subclassing DataFrame directly.
